# Convert query mongo to spring Mongooperations

Tags: java, sql, mongodb, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

Anyone can convert that query to mongo for java (org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoOperations)???

I haven't been able to get this search in Java.

Thank you.

```
db.respostas.aggregate([
   {
      "$group":{
         "_id":{
            "per":"$pergunta",
            "res":"$resposta"
         },
         "respostaCount":{
            "$sum":1
         }
      }
   },
   {
      "$group":{
         "_id":"$_id.per",
         "respostas":{
            "$push":{
               "resposta":"$_id.res",
               "count":"$respostaCount"
            }
         },
         "count":{
            "$sum":"$respostaCount"
         }
      }
   },
   {
      "$sort":{
         "count":-1
      }
   }
])
```

Comment: Please add what you've tried so far.

Comment: What I have is just that, because I do not know how to do @Veeram: `Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
   group("pergunta", "resposta")
    .count().as("respostaCount"),
   group(),
   sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "count")
 );`

Comment: please add the sample document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this.

```
Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
            group(fields().and("per", "$pergunta").and("res", "$resposta")).count().as("respostaCount"),
            group(fields("$_id.per")).push(new BasicDBObject("resposta", "$_id.res").append("count", "$respostaCount"))
                    .as("respostas").sum("respostaCount").as("count"),
            sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "count"));
```

Comment: After some tests, I saw that the information were correct. I made some changes and was thus: 

`Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
   group(fields().and("per", "$pergunta").and("res", "$resposta")).count().as("respostaCount"),
   group(fields("$_id.per")).push(new BasicDBObject("resposta", "$_id.res").append("count", "$respostaCount")).as("respostas"),
   sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "count"));`

It lacked only the sum of all the answers, I tried to put a `.sum ("$respostaCount").as("count")` at the end, but it didn't work, then removed.

Comment: Updated answer. Please verify.